# Install nodeJs in background on Heroku alongwith Jdk

Tags: java, node.js, heroku

I've a java web application and I want to install node server in the background so  I can execute js files from java in **Heroku**.
I want to execute `node myFile.js`

Comment: And I want newbies to really read through the stuff at the  [help] so that they understand how/what to ask here. Hint: not like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the Node.js buildpack to you app by running:

```
$ heroku buildpacks:add heroku/nodejs
```

And make sure you have a `package.json` file in your app.